# How can I raise a mouse event in WPF / C# with specific coordinates?

Tags: c#, wpf, mouseevent

I'd like to raise a mouse event (a click, mousedown, or mouseup) by taking a user's click anywhere in a WPF window and translating it by a known difference, e.g. click at x,y, raise the click event at x+100, y+100.

The underlying problem is that there's a display monitor that physically moves relative to an overlaying touch screen.  Rather than recalibrating the touchscreen with every move, I'd like to add the translation offset to the click event.

I've looked at the Win32 API for mouse_event and its superseding function, SendInput.  I admit I'm lost as I'm not very familiar with the API.

Surely this is a simple problem to solve, but I can't find example code anywhere that gets me to where I can implement a solution.  Any help, pointers, or solid examples of how to add this to my code behind would be appreciated.

Thanks
Mark

Comment: Can't you do this adjustment in the handlers?

Answer (score 10):

Win32 API won't work with WPF, this [link](http://www.wpfwiki.com/Default.aspx?Page=WPF%20Q8.6&AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1) might help

```
 // Copied the snippet of code from the link above, just to help future readers
 MouseEventArgs e = new MouseEventArgs(Mouse.PrimaryDevice, 0);
 e.RoutedEvent = Mouse.MouseEnterEvent;

 youUIElement.RaiseEvent(e);
 // Or
 InputManager.Current.ProcessInput(e);
```

Comment: Thank you, Waleed, I think this gets me a little further down the road.  What I still don't understand, however, is how to do the translation.  Where do I specify the new coordinates of the translated cursor in the event args, e in the snippet above.


Once the coordinates are set, since I don't know the UI element that will be under the new coordinates (it may just be blank window space), does ProcessInput(e) automatically figure this out?  Do I need to set the routing strategy to Tunneling or do something else?

Comment: Well, you should use Event Bubbling to catch every specific event raised on a child element. once captured, you'll get a reference to the UIElement that raised the event, you can then specify the new coordinates and forward them. to detect if the coordinates are outside the client area, just try : if (this.Clip.Bounds.Bottom > newY || this.Clip.Bounds.Left > newX dont) where this refers to your main window

Comment: The Link is dead