# WPF - Generate a mouse down, move and up with specified coordinates (in test)

Tags: c#, wpf, teststack

I need to generate mouse down, mouse move and finally mouse up events to implement a drag-box which performs a calculation based on the size of the box.

I've looked at 3 ways of accomplishing this:

1. TestStack.White - I can perform Click() and DragAndDrop() actions on the UI, but it seems not to be possible to perform MouseDown, MouseMove and MouseUp
2. Raising mouse events as suggested here [How can I raise a mouse event in WPF / C# with specific coordinates?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6325956/how-can-i-raise-a-mouse-event-in-wpf-c-sharp-with-specific-coordinates) Problem here is that I can't Mock the MouseDevice (or inherit from it) so I don't see any way to set the required coordinates
3. Using [InputSimulator](https://github.com/michaelnoonan/inputsimulator) to perform the clicks:

   `inputSimulator.Mouse.LeftButtonDown();
   inputSimulator.Mouse.MoveMouseBy(5, 3);
   inputSimulator.Mouse.LeftButtonUp();`
    
   the problem is that this does seem to trigger anything when used in a unit test

Ideally I would wrap the Mouse and pass in as a dependency (so I can mock it using Moq), but I don't think this is possible, hence why I'm trying to generate the mouse events.

I guess what I'm trying to accomplish here is to be able to set the mouse coordinates of the MouseDevice so that I can raise the events on the UserControl I'm testing but I'm not sure if this is possible..

Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: how about this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8561755/attempting-to-simulate-mouse-click-drag ?

Comment: I believe that's how InputSimulator works, in the meantime I've tried this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23903673/mouse-click-event-ir-respecive-of-display-scaling which is similar. The issue really is that I can raise the mouse events on the control but nothing I'm doing will change the pointer position which is always {0,0}

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
MouseDevice mouseDev = InputManager.Current.PrimaryMouseDevice;
```

Comment: A suggestion to try something belongs in comments. It's not an answer.